# Stylus on Mac: I get error trying to install it

Tags: node.js, macos, css, terminal, stylus

About 2 months ago I installed Node, I remember I had problem to do this, but I got it.

Now I am trying to install Stylus in Terminal and I can't, and I get this message:

> MacBook-Pro-de-Antony:~ antony$ node -v
>   v8.9.1
>   MacBook-Pro-de-Antony:~ antony$ sudo npm install -g stylus
>   /usr/local/bin/stylus -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus
>   + stylus@0.54.5
>   updated 1 package in 2.07s
>   MacBook-Pro-de-Antony:~ antony$ stylus -v
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:641
>       if (err) throw err;
>           ^
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '-v'
>   MacBook-Pro-de-Antony:~ antony$

My question is :

Do I have to "active" Node before to do this?
or what I am doing wrong?

I am using MacOS Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to run it within Node. It is ok to do it where you were doing it (in the command line).

The problem: `-v` is not a valid parameter. To see its version you should do: `stylus --version` or `stylus -V` (with an uppercase V).

`stylus --help` will show you all the options available.

Comment: Thank you man, so I don't have any problem with Stylus then... I can see what version I have.